# How to break out a function without return or break in Python

Tags: python, loops, break

I'm dfs traversing between nodes a and b, however when I break the loop at node b the algorithm continues. Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

def Graph():
    G=nx.Graph()

    k = 30

    G.add_edge(1,2)
    G.add_edge(2,3)
    G.add_edge(1,3)

    for i in range(2,k+1):
        G.add_edge(2*i-2,2*i)
        G.add_edge(2*i-1,2*i)
        G.add_edge(2*i-1,2*i+1)
        G.add_edge(2*i,2*i+1)

    G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(), color='never coloured')
    G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(), label = -1)
    G.add_nodes_from(G.nodes(), visited = 'no')

    return G

def dfs(G,a,b,u):
    global i
    G.node[u]['visited'] = 'yes'
    i += 1
    G.node[u]['label'] = i
    print(u)
    print("i", i)
    for v in G.neighbors(u):
        if v == b:
            G.node[v]['visited'] = 'yes'
            i += 1
            G.node[v]['label'] = i
            print("b is ", v)
            print("distance from a to b is ", G.node[v]['label'])
            break### the problem area, doesn't break out the function
        elif v != b:
            if G.node[v]['visited'] == 'no':
                dfs(G,a,b,v)
G=Graph()
a=1
b=19
i = 0
print('Depth-First-Search visited the following nodes of G in this order:')
dfs(G,a,b,a)  ### count the DFS-path from a to b, starting at a
print('Depth-First Search found in G7 a path between vertices', a, 'and', b, 'of length:', G7.node[b]['label'])
print()
```

I have tried returning out of the for loop, tried using break and also tried try/catch methods. Is there any elegant way to break out this function or will I have to rewrite it as it doesn't recurse through all neighbors of u?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not `break` or `return`, but that you use recursion and you don't stop the loop in each recursive call. What you need to do is to return a result from your `dfs` function that tells whether you found your node or not, and then break the loop inside your `else` block if the recursive call did find it. Something like this:

```
def dfs(G,a,b,u):
    global i
    G.node[u]['visited'] = 'yes'
    i += 1
    G.node[u]['label'] = i
    print(u)
    print("i", i)
    for v in G.neighbors(u):
        if v == b:
            G.node[v]['visited'] = 'yes'
            i += 1
            G.node[v]['label'] = i
            print("b is ", v)
            print("distance from a to b is ", G.node[v]['label'])
            return True
        elif v != b:
            if G.node[v]['visited'] == 'no':
                found = dfs(G,a,b,v)
                if found:
                    return True
    return False
```

Note how this propagates the successful result back up through your entire call stack.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I often use global flag variable to indicate that the searching is finished. For example **path_found**.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, your problem is not that you can't exit the function.

The problem is that you are not breaking out from recursion. There are many ways of fixing this.

This is one of many examples. By returning True and checking that in every call, you start bubbling up and skipping at every loop along your recursion. You can understand the True value as 'path found'

```
def dfs(G,a,b,u):
    global i
    G.node[u]['visited'] = 'yes'
    i += 1
    G.node[u]['label'] = i
    print(u)
    print("i", i)
    for v in G.neighbors(u):
        if v == b:
            G.node[v]['visited'] = 'yes'
            i += 1
            G.node[v]['label'] = i
            print("b is ", v)
            print("distance from a to b is ", G.node[v]['label'])
            return True
        elif v != b:
            if G.node[v]['visited'] == 'no':
                if dfs(G,a,b,v):
                    return True
```